# Why does docker hub include images of (what seems like) whole operating systems?

Tags: docker, docker-image, dockerhub

I was browsing docker hub and noticed images of operating systems such as Ubuntu or Alpine.
I am new to Docker but as I understand the whole point of containers is that they don't store the OS. In this case, why do such images exist?

Answer (score 3):

> why do such images exist?

Because you need a foundation from which to build your own images.

The base os images (like the `alpine` or `ubuntu`) images are typically minimal images that contain only core Unix utilities (like a shell and tools such as `ls`, `cp`, `mv`, `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, etc) and a package manager. These are the building blocks you use to build your own images.

A typical `Dockerfile` -- the instructions used to build an image -- will often look broadly like:

```
FROM <some base image>

RUN <install a bunch of packages>

COPY <my local files into the image>
```

Without these  base images, the process of creating new container images would be substantially more difficult.

Comment: And if you didn't have those utilities in your image, of a specific version that you selected as your base, but instead somehow could use the versions from the host OS, your container would have to deal with the differences between host systems, which you would not want.  So, known base images are a Good Thing.